# Different running time on different Visual Studio platforms?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, portability, timing

I ran the same project under different VS platforms, the time were as follows:

- VS2010 - x64: **114 ms**
- VS2010 - x32: **1,078 ms**
- VS2013 - x64: **112 ms**
- VS2013 - x32: **84 ms**

So I have the following questions:

1. Is this normal that time varies largely under different VS platforms?
2. What time should I count on?

Other info:

- All are running in release mode without debugging (Ctrl+F5).
- All the time has already been averaged over computation of a number of times.
- All the tests are taken on the same PC.

Comment: Did you clean & re-build before each trial? Before all the trials, are both VS2010 & VS2013 already both installed?

Comment: @Raptor I tried clean & re-build, turned out similar results. And, yes, both VS2010 and VS2013 are installed.

Comment: Depends on many things such as what is the code you are testing? What does the compiler output look like? Did you run it N times and take an average? Etc.

Comment: 1 more thing, did they use same .NET Framework version? Different versions of .NET Framework may be the root cause of time difference.

Comment: @paulm What do you mean by the compiler output? All the time has already averaged over a number of times.

Comment: Usual method is to do quite a few, then discard the highest and lowest values before averaging the remainder. Are there any other processes on the box that may be skewing the results (antivirus / database / windows search index etc)?

Comment: @Raptor I'm not quite sure about what you said. This is a C++ project, where can I see the versions of the .NET framework version?

Comment: Oh, I overlook it's a C++ project. However, different VS uses different MSBuild toolset. Newer version should have performance upgrade in theory.

Comment: Probably worth running the exe directly rather than Ctrl+F5 from the IDE - even in Release builds it adds some overhead. Also, look at project defaults, there is some vectorisation in later VS releases but I'm not sure what 2010 has.

Comment: By compiler output I mean the generated machine code

Comment: @paulm I have not gone that deep yet. Could you guide me how to get their machine code under VS?

Comment: @Raptor I just tried running their exe directly, again, turned out similar results.

Comment: @paulm I figured out how to check out their machine code under `Debug>Window>Disassembly`. I will compare them now. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.  We've just done a lot of this type of testing over a very small bit of code. Admittedly under UNIX, but the principles and problems are there same.

That 32-bit VS2010 result is surprising, but I'd be speculating about why.  Instead run a profiler over the code. That'll show you where all that time is being taken.  Then you can compare the  assembly language outputs from the different versions at that hot spot and the answer will inevitably pop out.

And to answer your two specific questions:

**Timing guarantees**
Unless you can control the hardware specification and the other software running on the target system  then there are no guarantees of time.

**Timing variation by compiler**
The time may vary by platform, compiler and compiler version.  However by using the profiler you can conform that the time-critical code you have is as good as it can be for any particular build.

**Reference material**

1. Profiling under Windows:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx
2. Docs on optimizing C++ and asm: http://www.agner.org/optimize/
3. Skip the first 20 minutes:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc Mike Acton shows the
   difference in assembly language outputs between different compilers
   and talks about optimization techniques.